# why is this reference null?

Tags: java

The following code is from Bates and Sierra:

```
public class Book {
    private String title; // instance reference variable

    public String getTitle() {
       return title;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
       Book b = new Book();
       String s = b.getTitle(); // Compiles and runs
       String t = s.toLowerCase(); // Runtime Exception!
    }
}
```

Why does `String t = s.toLowerCase()` cause a runtime exception when `String s = b.getTitle()` does not?

Comment: Post the error log also.

Comment: wow, 5 answers in less than a minute..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null references can be passed on as many times as needed, the NPE will occur **only** when you want to actually do something with the reference. To avoid the NPE, do something like

```
private String title = ""; // instance reference variable
```

That way, your `title` var will not be `null` when the Book Object is created

Comment: "only when you want to actually do something with the reference"                                                                                                                                 Now I get it! It can be null and referenced unless you want to do something with it in which case an error is generated. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you put your mouse below the numbers on the top left of people's answers, a hollowed out checkmark will be displayed. Click it and it turns green. That's it!

Answer (score 3):

It's easy: the b reference to Book is not null, but you never assigned a value to title.  It's null.

Answer (score 2):

Because title is never given any value. Non-primitive instance fields, like `title`, default to a value of `null`. So when you say `b.getTitle()`, that returns `null`. Then `s` is `null`, and when you try to dereference `null`, meaning use the `.` operator on it, you get a NullPointerException. Try:

```
Book b = new Book(); // b is now a Book object with a null title
b.title = "Programming Java"; // b's title is now a String instead of null
String s = b.getTitle(); // s is now the title that we added to the book
String t = s.toLowerCase(); // t is now the same title in lower case
```

Answer (score 1):

`new Book()` will make a book instance with null  title `private String title;`.

when you try `String t = s.toLowerCase();` s is null and hence the result

Answer (score 0):

**Objects** in java get `null` as `default value`, **String** is an `object` thus if not initialized it would be **null**.

> Why does String t = s.toLowerCase() cause a runtime exception when
>   String s = b.getTitle() does not?

Well, `b` is initialized thus it would not **throw NPE** when invoked its method, however `b.getTitle()` would return `null` as `title` isn't initialized, thus you get `NPE` when you invoke `toLowerCase()` on s (which is null).

```
String s = b.getTitle(); ---> s=null;
String t= s.toLowerCase(); ---> t= null.toLowerCase();
Throws NPE;
```

Answer (score 0):

`b` is a valid initialized `Book` object. However no title is defined. So `b.getTitle()` returns `null`. With `s.toLowerCase()` you try to execute a method on `null` which causes a NullPointerException.

You can Avoid this by giving title a default value:

```
private String title = "default title..";
```